# Are these examples of functional requirement?

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, software-design

Creating a dynamic user interface based on values read from a database API

Displaying relevant car information upon a tap gesture on an element

Validate QR codes using a QR Code Reader

The system must authenticate User - (login and registration)

The system must validate user input - (display an error if no input provided)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **Functional Requirement (FR)** is a description of services that a software must offer.
FR describers a software system or its component.
A function is nothing but inputs to the software system, its behavior, and outputs. It can be a calculation, data manipulation, business process, user interface, or any other specific functionality which defines **what function a system is likely to perform**.

The requirements that are mentioned above are functions to a system (**In this case an android app**).So, yes these requirements are **Functional Requirements**.